# add root certificate to chromium bundle

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate, chromium, ca

I'm trying to add my own root certificate to chromium at compile time.
I have changed the source code but the certificate does not appeared in the "Authorities" list.
here is my local changes :

1. generate ca certificate and add it to src/net/data/ssl/ev_roots/
2. update src/net/cert/ev_root_ca_metadata.cc
3. rebuild